# why calling cd shell command through system() or execvp() from a child process won't work?

Tags: shell, command, system, cd, execvp

I understand that i am supposed to use chdir() but I just need an explanation as to why calling cd shell command through system or execvp() from a child process would not work? Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `chdir` only modifies the environment of the current process. It can't touch the environment of the parent.

See also [the link](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part2/section-8.html) posted by tripleee.

Comment: This is a way too frequent FAQ.  http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part2/section-8.html

Comment: im a beginner in c, please explain.. Your answer answers why I have to use chdir or..? but why can i not use cd through exec() or system().. Thanks

Comment: My answer explains why you **can't** change the directory. `cd` relies on `chdir`.

Comment: Thanks, im not the (for as long as i've got it working) person; i try understand what im doing. Thanks again !!